# Getting value of line after a match in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a simple python script that will search for a matching word but only print out the line below the matched word.

My xml contains content like this

```
  <field name="some.title">
    <value>VALUE1</value>
  </field>
  <field name="some.otherTitle">
    <value>VALUE2</value>
  </field>
  <field name="MATCHING.Title">
    <value>VALUE3</value>
  </field>
  <field name="some.alternativeRandomTitle">
    <value>VALUE4</value>
  </field>
```

I'm able to read through the input and match the word and print it, but how would I get only the value below it? In this example I'm searching for MATCHING.Title but only want VALUE3 to be printed. I've been searching around but having trouble with getting it working.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    matching = re.search(r'<field name="MATCHING.Title">',line)
    print matching.group()
```

Comment: Perhaps an XML parsing module would be more appropriate than `re`. Then you could do `[field.value.text for field in document.find_all("field") if field["name"] == "MATCHING.Title"]`. (that's just example syntax, it probably wouldn't look exactly like that)

Answer (score 0):

for almighty regex...

```
str1 = """
  <field name="some.title">
    <value>VALUE1</value>
  </field>
  <field name="some.otherTitle">
    <value>VALUE2</value>
  </field>
  <field name="MATCHING.Title">
    <value>VALUE3</value>
  </field>
  <field name="some.alternativeRandomTitle">
    <value>VALUE4</value>
  </field>
"""

print re.search(r'<field name="MATCHING.Title">\s(.*)', str1).group(1)
```